# RTF2FO converted API used in java to extract and merge RTF content to Existing XSL

Tags: java, xslt

Does anyone have idea regarding the RTF2FO 3.5.0.

I am trying this to convert rtf to fo file,it worked... but i am facing a issue in table formation and pictures.

1. Can I set a path were i can save picture from RTF files with out the
   default folder   (.images), which the RTF2FO create in default.
2. Can I set the table layout and the width properties in percentage
   "%", default is "pt".

can any one help me out.